# Error al exportar base de datos con imagenes o archivos

Tags: php, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Tengo una base de datos que tienen archivos PDF subidos, necesito hacer periódicamente un respaldo de dicha base de datos, pero me sale error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo deja exportar cuando le borro los archivos PDF, tambien sucede el mismo error si subo imagenes

Comment: ¿Por qué tu archivo termina llamándose `.part`? Da la impresión de que es un backup incompleto. Por otra parte, ¿qué herramienta usas para hacer el backup y qué es lo que pretendes hacer con ese backup aquí, quieres restaurarlo, si es eso, por qué quieres restaurarlo o qué es lo que quieres hacer?

Comment: He usado XAMP, pero ya encontre la solucion.
No puedo exportar archivos e imagenes en xamp, pero si mi base de datos lo lleno en mysql Workbrench, si me deja hacer el respaldo con archivos incluidos, ya lo solucione.
Gracias